# unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

So I'm looking around stack overflow, I see a lot of these unrecognized selector sent to instance error messages. Some ARC related, most non ARC related. What I essentially I am doing is calling a NSTimer to call a method every 6 seconds to change the file path of the array for a photo. (An automated banner if you will.) When 6 seconds has passed, I get this error message:

```
2014-07-10 11:04:35.152 ysysy[435:57924] -[TableViewController animateFunction]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x156989f0
2014-07-10 11:04:35.154 ysysy[435:57924] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[TableViewController animateFunction]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x156989f0'
```

I call a setBannerTimer method inside of the viewWllAppearMethod:

```
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setBannerTimer) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

setBannerTimer then triggers a string method called animate function every 6 seconds:

```
- (void) setBannerTimer {


    self->bannerTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:6 target:self selector:@selector(animateFunction) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }
```

Animatie function:

```
 +(NSString *)animateFunction

return photoPath;
}
```

Hopefully I laid my problem out for everyone to easily understand. I must be doing something syntactically wrong with my method right? I am so close! Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Uh, you've declared `animateFunction` as a class method, yet the timer function expects an instance method.

Comment: Try with `-(NSString *)animateFunction` instead of ` +(NSString *)animateFunction`, you're calling a class method.

Comment: Dude, I seriously think you need to start over with iOS development. I see bad design everywhere.

Comment: @duci9y hah! Yeah still learning this lingo. I agree with you, Java is more my native language.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I debug 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25853947/how-can-i-debug-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not about ARC, scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:target:selector:userInfo:repeats should have an **instance** method selector, **not a class method** one;

=> Call a

```
- (NSString *)animateFunction
```

instead of a

```
+ (NSString *)animateFunction
```